# what is AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, testng

I have a TestNG class which is like the following:

```
public class WebAPITestCase extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests{.....}
```

I was trying to understand what this means `extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests`.

How does it work and what is the use of it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please read the javadoc:

> AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests is an abstract base test class that
>   integrates the Spring TestContext Framework with explicit
>   ApplicationContext testing support in a TestNG environment. When you
>   extend AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests, you can access a protected
>   applicationContext instance variable that you can use to perform
>   explicit bean lookups or to test the state of the context as a whole.

Basically a spring application context will be setup for the test class.

If that still doesn't make sense I'd recommend you read [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testcontext-support-classes-testng).

Answer (score 3):

First, [TestNG](https://testng.org/doc/index.html) (stands for Test Next Generation) is a testing framework inspired from JUnit and NUnit but introducing some new functionalities that make it more powerful and easier to use like test that your code is multithread safe, powerful execution model, etc.

The class `AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests` includes the spring `ApplicationContext`. To make it available when executing TestNG test, `AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests` has methods annotated with **TestNG** annotations like [`@BeforeClass`](http://static.javadoc.io/org.testng/testng/6.9.4/org/testng/annotations/BeforeClass.html) and [`@BeforeMethod`](http://static.javadoc.io/org.testng/testng/6.9.4/org/testng/annotations/BeforeMethod.html).

So to have this functionality of running TestNG with Spring components, all it left to do is to extend `AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests`.

BTW, `AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests` extends `AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests`. It not only provides transactional support but also has some convenience functionality for JDBC access.